# Flat List not Rendering data on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to showing data Report Book From API. But the result is nothing like in this picture

[image: No Data]

and this is before showing data base on date

[image: Data based on id book]

and here is the code of reportbooksummary.js

```js
class ReportBookSummary extends Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {

            isLoading: true,
            id_book: '',
            startdate: '',
            enddate: '',
            data: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchdata();
    }

    fetchdata = async () => {
        let id_book = this.props.navigation.state.params.id_book;
        let TanggalStart = this.props.navigation.state.params.TanggalStart;
        let TanggalEnd = this.props.navigation.state.params.TanggalEnd;
        const response = await fetch('http://192.168.0.21/library-api/reportbook.php?id_book=' + id_book + '&TanggalStart=' + TanggalStart + '&TanggalEnd=' + TanggalEnd);
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: responseJson });
    };


    _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: '#228B22', margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', borderTopRightRadius: 40,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 40, borderBottomEndRadius: 40, borderBottomLeftRadius: 40
        }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> ID Book:    {item.id_book}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Book Name:  {item.book_name}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Author:   {item.author}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Description:  {item.description}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Book Price: {item.book_price}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> ID Publication: {item.id_publication}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> ID Branch: {item.id_branch}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Qty: {item.qty}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Rental Qty: {item.rental_qty}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Image Name: {item.imagename}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Image Path: {item.imagepath}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, margin: 15, justifyContent: 'center', color: 'white' }}> Entry Date: {item.entry_date}</Text>
            <Text style={{ height: 2, backgroundColor: 'white' }}></Text>
        </View>
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.headerTxt}>Report Book</Text>
                <View style={styles.subView}>
                    <Text style={styles.subTxt}>List Report Book</Text>


                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={this._renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ReportBook')}>
                        <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Go Back to Report Book</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer: {

        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'

    },

    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#228B22',
        height: 700,
    },
    subView: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: 399,
        marginTop: 240,
        borderTopRightRadius: 40,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
    },
    headerTxt: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        position: 'absolute',
        marginTop: 140,
    },
    subTxt: {
        color: 'black',
        marginTop: 20,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginLeft: 40,
    },
    nameInput: {
        height: 40,
        width: 270,
        marginLeft: 40,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    btn: {
        height: 50,
        width: 200,
        backgroundColor: '#228B22',
        borderRadius: 80,
        marginLeft: 70,
        marginTop: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    btnTxt: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    endView: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    endTxt: {
        fontSize: 15,
        marginTop: 30,
        marginLeft: 60,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    endBtn: {
        marginLeft: 50,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    loginTxt: {
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 24,
    },
});

export default ReportBookSummary;
```

Is something wrong about my js code? i thought this one should be working properly

Comment: this is import what i'm using 
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Picker
  } from 'react-native';
  import React, { Component, setState } from 'react';
  import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';

Comment: Try data={response}

Comment: its already working thanks